# The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available, when using Ropsten Network

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, javascript, nodejs, ropsten

My following code previously works perfectly at Ganache, but when i switched it to Ropsten Network, it give captioned error. 
**Here is Code:**

```
async function finalSettersFunctions(){
  var myFunc; 
  var  myContAddr ;
  for(i=0; i < contractAddressess.length; i++) {
      myContAddr = contractAddressess[i]
    for(j=1; j<finalSetters[i].length; j++) {
          myFunc = finalSetters[i][j];

            try {
              await web3.eth.sendTransaction(
                {from:account1,
                to:myContAddr,
                data: myFunc
                    }, function(err, receipt) {console.log("Normal Setters: ",receipt)});
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(" Normal Setters: ERROR !", error); 
            }
    }
  }
}
```

It should be noted that all my setters function are in encoded form, means all their methodId and parameters are embedded i.e. **myFunc= 0x34fcd000000000033400000000000678888800000000........**

**Here is detailed error:**

```
The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available
    at Object.ErrorResponse (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:29:16)
    at C:\Users\aa\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js:140:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:102:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1143:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

**Update**: my provider is `Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/`

**Update 2:** i have changed my code as per comments (to sign my transaction and sendSignedTransaction) .... as is my new code

```
async function finalSettersFunctions(){
  var myFunc; 
  var  myContAddr ;
  for(i=0; i < contractAddressess.length; i++) {
      myContAddr = contractAddressess[i]
    for(j=1; j<finalSetters[i].length; j++) {
          myFunc = finalSetters[i][j];
          /// here i have changed !
          rawTx = {
            nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1),
            gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
            gasLimit: '0x2710',
            to: myContAddr,
            data: myFunc
          }
          var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
          tx.sign(privateKey2);
          var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
          web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
          .on('receipt', console.log);
    }
  }
}
```

**but it give this error** `Error: Returned error: invalid sender`

Comment: On ganache the accounts are unlocked by default, you should sign the transaction and use send signed transaction instead

Comment: Have you unlocked `account1` on infura? Of course, that's not possible (and you wouldn't want it to be either).

Comment: @MajdTL thanks for your response... could explain it with solution by given it in your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you unlocked `account1` on Infura?

Of course, that's not possible (and you wouldn't want it to be either).

This mode of operation is available only when you're using your own private node, so that others will not be able to exploit your account.

And even then, it is not a recommend mode of operation, since anyone hacking your node will be able to exploit your account at will.

So it is designated primarily for testing purpose (as is the case with Ganache, see the comment to your question).

Otherwise, it is recommended to sign the transaction with your private key and then send it to the node (and again - with Infura nodes being public, it is not just the recommended mode of operation, but the only one available).

Comment: i am signing .. but its give Error: Returned error: invalid sender... rawTx = {
            nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1),
            gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
            gasLimit: '0x2710',
            to: myContAddr,
            data: myFunc
          }
          var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
          tx.sign(privateKey2);
          var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
          web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
          .on('receipt', console.log);

Comment: @AmirAli: That's a different error which deserves a different question, if I am to judge by the amount of information that you posted in the comment above.

Comment: i have updated such error in my update 2.. if still it deserve a different question, i can post it .. no problem for me ..

Comment: @AmirAli: "but it give this error `Error: Returned error: invalid sender`" - which lines gives this error???

Comment: btw. the another error has been solved by  var tx = new Tx(rawTx, {chain:'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg'}); thanks for your time

Comment: @AmirAli: NP :)

Answer (score 0):

async function finalSettersFunctions(){
  var myFunc; 
  var  myContAddr ;
  for(i=0; i < contractAddressess.length; i++) {
      myContAddr = contractAddressess[i]
    for(j=1; j

```
        try {
          await web3.eth.sendTransaction(
            {from:account1,
            to:myContAddr,
            data: myFunc
                }, function(err, receipt) {console.log("Normal Setters: ",receipt)});
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(" Normal Setters: ERROR !", error); 
        }
}
```

}